# how to find argument of $\sin(\sqrt{(\frac{k}{m})}*t+\phi)$ in a physics question about a spring?

Tags: trigonometry, physics

[I think this question is more related to math than physics, so I've thought this forum is more approriate for the following question, let me know if it's not the case]

I have this equation (it's the equation of motion of a spring),
$$x(t) = x_r + A\cdot\sin(\sqrt{ \frac{k}{m}}\cdot t+\phi)$$

I need to find parameter $t$, and in order to find $t$ I need to find argument of sine, and after that it's only algebra. But the problem is in finding argument of sine. I can't do this way $$\frac{x(t)-x_r}{A} = \arcsin([...])$$ because I don't know $x(t)$, and therefore it's not possible to use inverse trig function of sine, based on my trig knowledge, it's the only way to find argument.

Comment: You are correct you can not find $t$ if you have the implicit t dependency on the lhs - is the question to find a given $t=T$ for an initial condition $x(T)$?

Comment: ah, okay, I forgot the fact that if I don't have initial condition is not possible to do anything, because of this implicit dependency on the left hand side, sometimes I forgot it and I say "what if I don't have that information, that, and that?", but physics doesn't work like this, and there are informations I *must* know. Thanks for the comment

Comment: I don't think it is implicit, the definition of $x(t)$ is the RHS. If you are trying to invert the formula say to get $t = t(x)$, applying arcsin should work.

Comment: @KevinS how do you invert the formula?

Comment: @KevinS agreed poor choice of words. At OP I am not sure what you mean :) - time is time, so it will take all values from 0 to the end of time. But you are looking for a specific value of $t$ so as the Kevin states, you need to know for the value of $x(t)$.

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini you have also done the inversion incorrect in your post $$[\cdots] = \arcsin\left(\frac{x(t) - x_r}{A}\right)$$ (using your notation

Comment: $t(x) = \sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}\bigg[arcsin\bigg(\frac{x-x_r}{A}\bigg) - \phi\bigg]$. In this way you should get the identity map when you compose the original expression for $x(t)$ into $t(x)$.